# How to write into a span without any padding?

Tags: css, margin, padding, font-size

Maybe this question has been already answer but i want to have a span which contains only one big letter with :

```
font-size : 300px;
```

but i can't erase the top and bottom margin

I can't post my image because i have'nt enought reputation !

I tried to adapt the line-height but my span is still as high as before !

Thanks

Comment: Have you reset (i.e: set to 0) the padding/margin with a css rule applied to that span?

Comment: Yes i did it ! In fact there is only margin above and below the span

Comment: Can you put your code (both html and css) in a jsfiddle? That would make it easier to debug.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2LHHv/

Comment: But this is how a font is rendered, it looks same in div, p or any other tag.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any margin or padding around your big "A".  You can tell because setting them to 0 doesn't affect anything: http://jsfiddle.net/KatieK/2LHHv/1/.

If you're wondering what's causing the empty space between `#container` and `#letter`, it's due to the extra spacing (due to `line-height` and the way text elements need spacing to handle both tall **H** and dangling **j** characters) inherent in inline-level elements. Try (ideally) adjusting the `line-height` of the parent, or setting `#letter { display: block; }`.